# Is there any way to recover from a printf()/puts() error?

Tags: c, error-handling, printf, stdout, code-generation

Whilst [interpreting and transpiling Brainfuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291082/kbf-a-brainfuck-interpreter-and-transpiler-in-c), I have this series of calls to `printf()`/`puts()`:

```c
while (ip < ops->count) {
        Op op = ops->items[ip];

        switch (op.kind) {
            case '+':
                printf("    t.mem[t.head] += %zu;\n", op.operand);
                ++ip;
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("    t.mem[t.head] -= %zu;\n", op.operand);
                ++ip;
                break;
            case '.':
                printf("    xputchar_many(&t, %zu);\n", op.operand);
                ++ip;
                break;
            case ',':
                printf("    xgetchar_many(&t, %zu);{\n", op.operand);
                ++ip;
                break;
            case '>':
                printf("    t.head += %zu;\n\n"
                       "    grow_tape_and_append_many_zeroes(&t);\n", op.operand);
                ++ip;
                break;
            case '<':
                printf("    t.head = t.head < %zu ? t.count - (%zu - t.head) : t.head - %zu;\n",
                       op.operand, op.operand, op.operand);
                ++ip;
                break;
            case '[':
                puts("    while (t.mem[t.head] != 0) {");
                ++ip;
                break;
            case ']':
                puts("    }");
                ++ip;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The calls to `puts()/printf()` are generating the code.

I have two questions:

Is there any chance of recovery after `printf()` fails (i.e. return a negative integer) or `puts()` fail (i.e. return `EOF`)? (I am of the opinion no.)

If no, is calling `fprintf(stderr, ...)` before exiting still useful? (I am of the opinion yes.)

Comment: Yes, I should move `++ip` at the end of the `switch` statement.

Comment: *"`Is there any chance of recovery after printf() returns a negative value?`"* what do you mean?

Comment: @gulpr I updated the question. Is it still ambiguous?

Comment: If it does, then your system or program is dead and no recovery is possible :)

Comment: Is this in a context where stdout is re-routed to some other form of output like a file or serial port? Otherwise I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Lundin `printf()`/`puts()` may be replaced with `fprintf()`/`fputs()` and output to some file. `stdout` can be re-routed. The problem is wrongly generated code, or half generated code, without an error indication.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of the code example; I assumed it's irrelevant and answered just the literal question. If you think your code and `xputchar_many` are important in some way, please clarify.

Comment: @anatolyg The calls to `puts()`/`printf()` were the relevant part. The code example was added because there is a difference in generating code with `printf()`  and printing `"Hello World."` to the console (for which I wouldn't bother checking the return value). I have removed the portion speaking of `xputchar_many()` albeit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any chance of recovery after `printf()` fails (i.e. return a negative integer) or `puts()` fail (i.e. return `EOF`)? (I am of the opinion no.)

There is unlikely to be anything that the program can do *by itself* to recover.  As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78179312/2402272) points out, you can clear the destination `FILE`'s error indicator and try again, but there's no particular reason to expect that that will be sufficient (but also no reason suppose that it couldn't be sufficient in any particular instance).

However, you're probably asking the wrong question.  You're writing a Brainfuck transpiler. The first two questions you should be asking here are

- *Is it worth trying to recover from I/O errors?*

  and
- *If not, then what should be done instead?*

I claim that no, for this utility, it is not worth spending time or effort on an error-recovery mechanism for I/O errors.  Such errors are unlikely to occur and unlikely to have good recovery options anyway, and the utility's role is not critical or sensitive.  A recovery strategy for such errors would very likely be a wasted effort.

Instead, then, the program should probably just attempt to print a diagnostic to `stderr` and exit with a failure status, or maybe even `abort()`.

You wrote in comments:

> The problem is wrongly generated code, or half generated code, without an error indication.

Either exiting with a failure status or terminating because of a signal (which would be the result of calling `abort()`) is detectable in the environment from which the program is launched, so either of these options provides an error indication that can alert about the generated code being faulty as a result of the kind of error you ask about.

There may be other indications the program can provide too.  For example, as @JonathanLeffler noted in comments, if the output were going to a regular file whose path the program knew, then it might attempt to remove that file when terminating because of an I/O error.  Whether that or any other such behavior would be desirable is a judgement for you to make.

Comment: If the output was being written to a file (rather than standard output), the output file could be removed when an error occurs — and the lack of an output file is also indisputable evidence that there was a problem.  OTOH, that might spoil some of the evidence about what went wrong.

Comment: Agreed, @JonathanLeffler, though of course, the removal could fail too.  For example, if the problem arose in the first place because the filesystem was unmounted or was remounted read-only.  I would characterize removing the output file as a possible additional failure-mode behavior, available when the destination was a file whose path was known to the program.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes. The `<stdio.h>` header file has a dedicated `clearerr` function to do just that. You could try displaying the error using `perror`, try to do `clearerr` and try again.

Possible use-case, suggested by Eric Postpischil:

> You are writing logs to some device. It fills, and `puts` returns an error due to insufficient space. You [...] remove old log files and try again.

The cppreference site gives a [slightly convoluted example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputwc) for an error which looks recoverable to me (I didn't try it):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

errno = 0;
if (fputwc(L'', stdout) == WEOF)
{
    if (errno == EILSEQ)
        puts("Encoding error in fputwc.");
    else
        puts("I/O error in fputwc.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

If `stdout` got errors, `stderr` could still be writable! Redirection is a common example (you could redirect `stdout` using a shell or `freopen`, while leaving `stderr` connected to the console).

Comment: Rather than `puts()` in code sample, consider `perror();`.

Comment: Be “But I can't imagine a situation where this could be useful in practice”: You are writing logs to some device. It fills, and `puts` returns an error due to insufficient space. You search for and remove old log files and try again.